# add1 does not exist in DOM How to Add?

Tags: javascript, html

I am having an issue with java-script and an HTML form.

I have a form and next to the form is a button called "add" when I click add the second form appears. Next to form 2 is another button called add1, when I click this button I am wanting the third form to display. For some reason only the first add button is working.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #newservicesetup1, #newservicesetup2 {
        display:none;
    }
</style>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function showform(theform) { 
    var showHides = new Array('newservicesetup1','newservicesetup2'); 
    for (i=0;i<showHides.length;i++) { 
        document.getElementById(showHides[i]).style.display= 
          (document.getElementById(showHides[i]).id == theform) ? 'block' : 'none'; 
    } 
}

function loadBehaviors () { 
    if (document.getElementById) { 
        document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() { showform('newservicesetup1'); }
        document.getElementById('add1').onclick = function() { showform('newservicesetup2'); }
    } 
} 

window.onload = loadBehaviors;
</script>
```

Comment: Are you sure there is an `add1` element on the page? Also, switch to using the array literal syntax, ie `var showHides = ['newservicesetup1', 'newservicesetup2'];`

Comment: You should never have to check for the existence of `document.getElementById`: No browser I can think of that has a javascript engine doesn't have the getElementById function. It just makes your code unnecessarily defensive.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a semicolon to the end of the assignments:

```
function loadBehaviors () { 
  if (document.getElementById) { 
    document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() { showform('newservicesetup1'); };
    document.getElementById('add1').onclick = function() { showform('newservicesetup2'); };
  } 
}
```

You can check your Javascript for syntax using [Online Javascript Lint](http://javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php).

Answer (score 0):

why not just

```
document.getElementById('add').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('newservicesetup1').style.display = 'block';
}
document.getElementById('add1').onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById('newservicesetup1').style.display = 'block';
}
```

that will show the correct forms when you click the appropriate button. if you want them to disappear when clicking again, you will only need a slight modification

Answer (score 0):

When loadBehaviors() is called, add1 does not exist in the DOM yet.  Bind to the event handler after you add it to the DOM.

Comment: How do I go about doing this?